Building an ASP.NET Core app for deployment
I'm using the dotnet CLI on macOS and am trying to build/compile my ASP.NET Core app. When I run dotnet build --arch win-x86 --self-contained true, I get an error

The specified RuntimeIdentifier 'osx-win-x86' is not recognized.

What's casuing this? In the command I'm specifying to target win-x86, not "osx-win--x86". What do I need to do to fix this?

This is due to the inappropriate use of -arch option. As specified in dotnet publish documentation, -arch option combines provided value with default one (which apparently for your machine is osx).
Instead of using -arch you should use -runtime or specify it inside <RuntimeIdentifier> element of your project file.
More on runtime identifiers here
